# Better way to transform data

Tags: data, dto

**Context**
Imagine complicated service that provides info about bank products, fees and so on.
Imagine complicated UI that deals with it.
UI and Service data formats are changed 1-2 times/month because of active development.
**Decision**
To make life of UI developers easier, we transform data into format that UI developers want.
E.g. we put objects into another level in tree, add fields like brokerFee and agentFee instead of providing map of fees with their types, etc.
**Current solution**
We use Java code to transform Service DTO (data transfer object) into UI DTO and back.
**Problem**
The code doesn't look good :) It's time-consuming to maintain.
XSLT transformation is not an option because it will be even harder to maintain.
**Idea**
Introduce Groovy because the syntax is easier to read.
**Question**
What are other options?
Any patterns/libraries/approaches that can simplify data transformation code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want a convention-based object-to-object mapper.  There is a .NET project called [automapper](http://automapper.org) which does this - I would look to it for inspiration, and for what patterns you may want to implement.  The most common is simply flattening a complex object into a simpler DTO with no nested properties.

From [their site](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki), some other things to take into account:

- Flattening
- Projection
- Configuration
- Validation
- Lists and Arrays
- Nested Mappings
- Custom Type Converters
- Custom Value Resolvers
- Null Substitution
- Before and after map actions
- Containers
- Mapping Inheritance
- Conditional Mapping
- Open Generics